# Python: how can I get an object's address in the __repr__ method?

Tags: python

How can I get an object's address for inclusion in the object representation, similar to how the default `__repr__` works?

```
>>> a=object()
>>> a
<object object at 0x1002c8090>

class Foo(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<my stuff, at '+obj_address+'>' # how do I get object address?
```

Comment: Nitpick: by convention, surround your `repr` result with `<>` if it isn't valid python syntax (but there is no requirement for non-`<>` `repr`s to be `eval`able).

Comment: @o11c, thanks, I didn't realize that.  updated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The address is the ID of the object in hex:

```
>>> o = object()
>>> repr(o)
'<object object at 0x1028ed080>'
>>> id(o)
4337881216
>>> hex(id(o))
'0x1028ed080'
```

Comment: More precisely, the `id()` of an object is "an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime". In the CPython reference implementation it happens to be the address, but it need not be.

Answer (score 6):

```
class Foo(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<my stuff, at 0x%x>' % id(self)
```

Comment: Probably more conventional to use `return 'my stuff, at 0x%08x' % id(self)`.

Comment: @martineau I guess that depends if you're running 32 or 64bit python, but I don't think the default `__repr__` puts leading zeros in anyway

Comment: Actually the 32-bit version _does_ pad with zeroes, I just got a `<object object at 0x01C984A8>` from it. Anyway, I meant the conventional way memory addresses are displayed. The interpreter's bitness can be determined from `sys.maxsize`, so the format string could be adjusted automatically.

Comment: @martineau odd, I'm not sure as in my 32bit version I get `<object object at 0x2404d8>`, and @MarkHarrison and @WilCooley both appear to have 9 chars in theirs, so I've no idea.